# pythonic way of setting values in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have these two codes:

```
message = {}
message['code'] = "001"
message['value'] = "Test Value"
```

and

```
message = {
    'code': "001",
    'value': "Test Value"
}
```

Both are working and correct when setting values in a dictionary, but which of this one is more use in work or more pythonic to use and why? I just got curious while i'm making a rest api. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have 3 operations to initialise a dictionary with values you already have when you could use only 1?

Comment: If you can define the whole structure in one step, surely that is simpler. If the values are collected through multiple calls, or computed in a sequence of steps, you may prefer to save values one by one on the dict as you get them, instead of saving each result to a variable and composing the complete dict at the end. But it is largely a matter of preference or judgement for each case.

Comment: @coldspeed hi, actually I just saw that code in one of the projects I am checking here at work. So the 2nd code is more pythonic?

Comment: @jdehesa oh I see, alright that is noted. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: Both have their advantages. You use the first one when someone gave you a massive dictionary which you only want to change 1 or 2 key-values. You use the second one if you know what key-values are up-front without any logic to compute these. Just for future references, when someone asks you which way is better/more used in software dev, the answer is likely BOTH.

Comment: alright thanks @TuanDT this is noted and a big help for me :) I have more understanding which one to use depending on the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're able to write the dictionary as a single literal, you should do that.

The only situation where multiple assignments make sense is if some of the assignments are in a block (eg, a condition or a loop).

Comment: Alright thanks! I got curious because of the code I saw in the other projects in our work. I now understand the use case of multiple assignments.